# Office Outlook, can't search contact in local folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

A friend, at work, has a folder contacts (with his personal contacts) in his local *.pst folder, When he writes a new message, whet he click on To.. it opens only the company's contacts. Also, i have noticed that when I click properties on his local folder, go to Outlook Addreess Book, the "Name of this address book" checkbox is unchecked and disabled. How can I repair this, so he can use his personal contacts folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
(As I mentioned this is for Office Outlook 2003)

- open Tools/E-Mail Accounts
- add new direcory or address book
- aditional address book
- select Outlook Address Book and click next
- go back to the original folder (in contacts)
- open properties
- in "Outlook Address Book" tab check the "Show this folder as an e-mail Address Book"
- hit ok and problem solved

:)

Answer (score 0):

As for the main symptom, you can manually set the address books that are used for name checking and their order of precedence.

In Outlook 2007:
Tools -> Address Book -> Tools -> Options

There, you can add address lists to the name checking process.

Comment: At work I have Office 2003 :)
I'll find I way to make it work